# How do I data bind in a new popup window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a beginner in C# WPF programming. I'm trying to pop up a new window(dialog) to which some information is passed. The new window is to show the information on itself.

I pass some variables through the constructor of the popup window(OrderEntry), and I want the popup window to show the variables within its textblock control. Very simple task. But it's not working. I guess I did something wrong regarding the data-binding in the popup window's XAML code, but I can't figure it out. What did I do wrong? Please help.

**The following is the MainWindow code-behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            Orders = da.GetOrders();
            OrdersGrid.ItemsSource = Orders;
        }

        private void OrdersGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Order item = (Order)OrdersGrid.SelectedItem;
            OrderEntry dialog = new OrderEntry(item);
            dialog.Show();
        }
    }
```

**The next is the XAML code for OrderEntry.xaml:**

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=_CustomerName}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

**The following is the class for the new popup window:**

```
public partial class OrderEntry : Window
    {
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public string _CustomerName { get; set; }

        public OrderEntry(Order order)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Order = order;
            _CustomerName = order.CustomerName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Urge you to go through databinding basics [data-binding-overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to use the code behind as the DataContext. In most of the cases we do binding using the ViewModel class. In your case, you can follow the following.

First you need to assign a name to your view OrderEntry in OrderEntry.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="OrderEntry"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Name="OrderEntry1"
Title="CodeBehindDataContext" Height="450" Width="800">
```

Then assign the binding as follows.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=OrderEntry1, Path=_CustomerName}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now change your OrderEntry constructor like below.

```
public OrderEntry(Order order)
{
    Order = order;
    _CustomerName = order.CustomerName;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Now I'm trying your solution. Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Set the datacontext of order window to itself.
Something like this

```
public partial class OrderEntry : Window
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public string _CustomerName { get; set; }

    public OrderEntry(Order order)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;//datacontext to itself
        Order = order;
        _CustomerName = order.CustomerName;
    }
}
```